# Github Branch Pulling and Commenting

Tags: branch, commit, pull

I have a project where I want to split it into 3 experiments, each path with a separate twist to it. Down the road, I will want to revert back to a previous iteration or go back to the original. If I pull from the other branch, will it completely replace my local files with the files form the other branch? To keep both iterations locally, should I just copy and paste the folder?

Also with commenting, what is the standard practice for commiting new updates? Every time I commit -m "new update", it replaces the old one and I can't see the history of commits.

Comment: Why are you pulling from another branch? Why don't you just check it out? And when you say "it replaces it," what do you mean? What replaces what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to question about viewing commit history, you can use: `git log` from your terminal in the project's root directory.
More info [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History).

From the git-scm webpage linked above:

> By default, with no arguments, `git log` lists the commits made in
>   that repository in reverse chronological order – that is, the most
>   recent commits show up first.

If you want to see all the differences, you can use the `-p` flag like so: `git log -p`.

A good recommendation from the same webpage is to use this command `git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s"` to see the log in a very readable format, something like:

`ca82a6d - Scott Chacon, 6 years ago : changed the version number
085bb3b - Scott Chacon, 6 years ago : removed unnecessary test
a11bef0 - Scott Chacon, 6 years ago : first commit`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Daenu, that is exactly what I did. The essential part was using git log to view the history of commits i.e. "...I can't see the history of commits." and the link was provided for more information about the git log command. What more were you expecting?

Comment: How's about giving some more info here?

Comment: I have added more information about the git log command. Still, unsure about the first half of the question as ddsnowboard pointed out, and the OP still hasn't clarified.

Comment: thumbs up! That is an answer